# AddThis: Facebook share ignores sharing configuration

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-opengraph, addthis

I'm trying to add an AddThis toolbox dynamically. Twitter & email receive some variables from the sharing configuration file, but the Facebook Share gets no info from there.

What am I missing?

HTML:

```
<span class="toolbox1 addthis_toolbox">
  <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_linkedin"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_email"></a>
</span>
```

JS:

```
toolbox_obj = $('.toolbox1').get(0);
addthis.toolbox(toolbox_obj,sharing_config,{title: 'aaa'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

**HTML**

```
<span class="toolbox1 addthis_toolbox"></span>​
```

**JS**

```
var tbx = $(".toolbox1").get(0),
svcs = {facebook: 'Facebook', twitter: 'Twitter', linkedin:'Linkedin', email: 'Email'};
$.each(svcs, function(k, v){
    $('<a></a>', { class:'addthis_button_'+k }).appendTo(tbx);
});
```

[**Working Example Here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/7jv2H/1/).

Comment: I probably wasn't clear..
The facebook button appears. But when I share, it doesn't get the title name to share from the sharing configuration object (`{title: 'aaa'}`).

Answer (score 0):

As written on [AddThis documentation](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381242-url-title#.UkrXdXe18h4):

> Some services, most notably Facebook and LinkedIn, do not use
>   parameters we send to them. Rather, they use meta tags to determine
>   the URL, title, and description to share.

some services (Facebook and Linkedin, for example) just ignore those configurations info because grab data from the Open Graph metatags.

So you should add Open Graph metatags to your HTML (try reading [this useful resource](http://www.addthis.com/blog/2012/09/27/debugging-sharing-to-facebook/)) and, if you encounter some problem with AJAX loaded content, maybe you can solve by forcing the url via the specific addthis method (obviously after the new content has been loaded):

```
addthis.update('share', 'url', window.location.href); // re-parse the url
addthis.ready(); // re-render the buttons.
```

Now the Share via Facebook will correctly gain its data from the open Graph metatags in page.

This has been a good resource to solve a similar problem I faced:

[AddThis buttons wont update to include fragment (#Hash Tag)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514878/addthis-buttons-wont-update-to-include-fragment-hash-tag)

Hope this can help, bye!

Answer (score 0):

```
<HEAD>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>

<meta property="og:title" content="Your Title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:image" content="Your Thumbnail Image Link" />
<meta property="og:url" content="Your URL" />
<meta name="description" content="Your Description" />

<HEAD>


<a name="fb_share" type="button_count" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php">Share</a>
```

Comment: Result will be:
http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-sV8ulEsNnSE/TdizQQPgNXI/AAAAAAAAAD4/JElqfUuGf60/s400/fb-share.jpg